# SQL Server & NODEJS : Undefined Connection error

Tags: sql-server, node.js, rest, sql-server-2008, express

I am trying to connect named instance of SQL Server 2008 using the nodejs `mssql` module:

```
var dbconfig={
        user:"sa",
        password:"password",
        server:"127.0.0.1",
        database:"products",
        options:{
            instanceName:"SQLEXPRESS"
        }
    };

// function to connect and execute query
var executeQuery = function(res,query){
    sql.connect(dbconfig,function(err){
        if(err)
        {
            console.log("connection error", err);
            res.send(err);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("connected!");
            var request = new sql.request();
            request.query(query,function(err,res){
                if(err)
                {
                    console.log("request error",err);
                    res.send(err);
                }
                else
                {
                    res.send(res);  
                }
            });
        }
    });
    sql.close();
};

//GET API
app.get("/api/products",function(req,res){
    var query ="select * from productcategory";
    console.log("Function call");
    executeQuery(res,query);
});
```

and I got this error:

> {"code":"ESOCKET","originalError":{"message":"Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:undefined - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:1433","code":"ESOCKET"},"name":"ConnectionError"}

I have enabled TCP\IP in SQL Server configuration Manager. Also SQL Server browser service is running.

Tried replacing the server name with 'localhost' and 'MyPCname' but still received the same error.

Please help me with the issue.

Comment: Are you sure that your instance name is `SQLEXPRESS?` Try connecting to your instance in SQL Server Management Studio and notate what it says the instance is, if any. You might not need `options:{ instanceName:"SQLEXPRESS"`

Comment: Server name: VAIO\SQLEXPRESS
Authentication: SQL Server Authentication
Login:sa

I can able to connect with the above parameters in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Updated 1433 port number in TCP/IP properties as well.